# java.io.IOException:Cannot run program "mysql":CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, mysql

Something is going wrong with my program for database recovery, this error hides my happiness:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql":CreateProcess error=2,
>   The system cannot find the file specified

file to be recovered is located in D:/Backup/backup.sql when I browse and open the file from this path then error appears when I click recovery button. Please help me solve this problem.
below is my code with `JFileChooser` for browsing file location.

```
browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

     String recPath = "";
         JFileChooser fc = null;
        if (fc == null) {
            fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    }
    int returnVal = fc.showDialog(null, "Open");
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        recPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        sourceField.setText(recPath);   


    }

}   

}

);


recoveryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    try{

        String databaseName ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB";
        String userName     ="abc";
        String password     ="123";
        String source       = sourceField.getText();
        int processComplete;

        String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql",databaseName, "--user=" + userName, "--password=" + password, "-e", "source"+source};

        //sava the command in a array
        Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);// execute the command

        processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();// get the result to variable

        if(processComplete==1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Restore Failed");
        }

        else if(processComplete==0){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Restore Completed");

        }

        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex); 

        }

        }


}   


);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add path to 'mysql' into 'Path' variables or specify full path in your code:

Try

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"\FULL PATH HERE\mysql",databaseName, "--user=" + userName, "--password=" + password, "-e", "source"+source};
```

instead of

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql",databaseName, "--user=" + userName, "--password=" + password, "-e", "source"+source};
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is correct in 2018/06/07...

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"\FULL PATH HERE\mysql",databaseName, "--user=" + userName, "--password=" + password, "-e", "source"+source};
```

A example will be :

```
String[] restoreCmd = new String[] { "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\bin\\mysql ", bd,"--user=" + usuario, "--password=" + password, "-e", "source " + pathToFile }
```

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "\FULL PATH To MySQL" 
eg : "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
to the environment path variables